# Circle stays within the borders of a triangle

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, geometry

I am currently trying to keep a circle within the borders of the surrounding triangle. Like in this picture:

[Image](http://postimg.org/image/6k7rmm9o9/)

I came up with two ideas so far.

1. I can check every time the user drags the circle, that all three lines of the triangle have no intersection with the circle
2. I calculate another smaller triangle where the lines have distance of on times the radius of the circle to the big triangle. After that I have to look if the center of the circle is within the smaller triangle

What do you think about any of those two solutions or do you know about superior ones?

Comment: I din't get your second point. Would you be able to elaborate it more?

Comment: Let's say you take the lines of the triangle and draw parallels with the distance of the radius of the circle. You then get another triangle within and as long as the center of the circle stays within I think it is okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one seems to be computationally less expensive, assuming the triangle does not change that often.

There seems to be plenty of [implementations](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/) for testing whether point lies within a triangle or not, which should be a bit more optimal than [checking for intersections](http://www.phatcode.net/articles.php?id=459)

As [Franz Busch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3960382/franz-busch) mentioned in the comments, you can easily determine the inset triangle by drawing parallel lines to the existing edges, assuming the triangle doesn't change that often, this should not be an overhead and thus the solution should work quite well.

Comment: Thank you i implemented the intersection method. Works very well and really efficient